# How to calculate the mean using two different data elements in a dataset?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am new to R and tiddyverse so I am having a bit of trouble. I have a large dataset which I have shortned for the sake of this problem. Basically, I need to calculate the mean age of samples from a specified sex "M" or "F."

| Sex | Age.at.diagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| F | 55.2 |
| M | 67.3 |
| M | 32.4 |
| F | 44.6 |
| F | 60.6 |

I should be seeing 49.85 when you input "M" for Males and 53.4 when you input "F" for Females.

My parameter inputs are "data" which is the metadata information for each sample and "sex" which is a string and tells us which sex to calculate the mean age on ("M" or "F").

```
mean_age_by_sex <- function(data, sex) {
  return (dplyr::group_by(data, Sex) %>%
            dplyr::summarize(mean_age = mean(data$Age))
            )
        
        
}
```

I thought this would work but get all sorts of errors. I'm thinking maybe I should be using the filter() function some how?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code

```r
mean_age_by_sex <- function(data, sex) {
  return (data %>% filter(Sex %in% c(sex)) %>% dplyr::group_by(Sex) %>%
            dplyr::summarize(mean_age = mean(Age.at.diagnosis))
  )
}
mean_age_by_sex(data,'F')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  Sex   mean_age
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 F         53.5
```